# Tab Bar in IOS application

Tags: ios, xcode, tabbar

hi guys i am beginner  IOS developer,   How do this part ( Tab Bar at the Botton of the screen ) in my application??

I marked on the picture: 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Taier answer is probably what you need. Otherwise you have plenty of tutorials on the internet:

https://www.simplifiedios.net/tab-bar-ios-swift-tutorial/
https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-from-scratch-with-swift-exploring-tab-bar-controllers--cms-25470

make custom tab bar:
https://guides.codepath.com/ios/Creating-a-Custom-Tab-Bar

also youtube is a good source of information and tutorials.
Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Welcome here!

You could create a project from a template with an already implemented tab bar, and just copy the code from that project to yours.

[image]